# Incorrect syntax near non-existent colon

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have this error when I try to debug this code in Visual Studio using ASP.NET. I have a `Room` and a `Booking` table that are both populated with data. The idea is for the statement to take user defined dates from a form (vb variable `arriveDate` and `departDate`) and size of room (vb variable `bedno`) and return all available rooms that match the user selected room size as well as return rooms that are not booked between the dates the user chose.

I have given the variables values already temporarily for testing purposes. I then use the results to populate a grid on a form page.

The code is as follows:

```
Dim bedno As Integer = 3
Dim arriveDate As Date = Date.FromOADate(12 / 8 / 2017)
Dim departDate As Date = Date.FromOADate(17 / 8 / 2017)

Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT RoomTable.RoomNumber, RoomTable.RoomBeds, RoomTable.RoomPricePerNight, BookingTable.RoomNumber, BookingTable.ArriveDate, BookingTable.DepartDate FROM RoomTable LEFT JOIN BookingTable ON ROoomTable.RoomNumber=BookingTable.RoomNumber WHERE(BookingRoomTable.RoomBeds = " & bedno & ") AND (" & arriveDate & "NOT BETWEEN BookingTable.ArriveDate AND BookingTable.DepartDate) AND (" & departDate & "NOT BETWEEN BookingTable.ArriveDate AND BookingTable.DepartDate)")
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
            cmd.Connection = con
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd

            Using dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                GridView1.DataSource = dt
                GridView1.DataBind()
            End Using
         End Using
      End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

All that comes up is an error saying

> Incorrect syntax near ':'"

and I can't figure out the problem. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with values.  You unexpected syntax errors.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What would you suggest instead? Not overly familiar with parameters.

Comment: Google vb.net parameterised query

Comment: "arriveDate", when converting it to a string it will get colons. You should inspect the generated string, then you'd see it. And **yes**, do use parameters, **don't write SQL code like this.**